# Fullpage.js and html-5-video fullscreen

Tags: javascript, html, video, fullpage.js

im using fullscreen.js for a project. if u come to a certain slide, say slide 3 / section 2, there is a video player, which u can switch to fullscreen.
but if u do that, fp seems to refresh the whole page: it moves from first section back to slide 3 / section 2. after that, the video is in fullscreen mode. the same if you cancle fullscreen mode.

Is there a way to avoid that behavior in fullpage?
something like
`$.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false);`

Answer (score 0):

found a solution :
in fullpage is a function called scrollPage().
If a video is loaded, stop the function.